# Adding into array list

Tags: java, arraylist

I am a Java newbie.. But I am sure I can get this done much efficient manner.

The purpose of this method is to add the product with an unique Id. If I the product as duplicate I should thrown an exception. Well, this sequence is not for multi-threaded environment.

```
public void addProduct(Product product)
        throws ProductAlreadyExistsException {
    product.id = ++nextId;
    this.id = product.id;

    Iterator<Product> it = allProducts.iterator();
    Product p= null;

    boolean flag= false;
    if (!allProducts.isEmpty()) {
        while(it.hasNext()){
            p= it.next();
            if ( p.getName() == product.getName())
                throw new ProductAlreadyExistsException(p.getName());
            else
                flag = true;
        }

    }
    else
        allProducts.add(product.id-1, product);

    if(flag){
        allProducts.add(product.id-1, product);
    }
}
```

What I want is something like this.

```
    for (Product p : allProducts) {
        if (p.getName() ==  product.getName() ) {
            throw new ProductAlreadyExistsException(p.getName());
        }
            allProducts.add(p);
        }
}
```

This does not work.
Thanks for guiding me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, you use `s1.equals(s2)` method to identify if two strings are equal.

```
 if ( p.getName() == product.getName()) // This will always return false, because references are compared here
```

What you should do is:

```
if ( p.getName().equals(product.getName()) )
```

NOTE: I'm assuming that `getName()` returns a string.

Comment: It is much better to implement equals() method in Product, so they can compare themselves to other objects. While doing so, also remember to implement hashCode. IDEs can automatically generate those two methods for you. About the equals and hashCode contract, read [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/269905/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/hashcode-equals-contract).

Comment: I made the above changes and it worked much better. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

In general, there's no guarantee granted that a `List` of any kind will contain only unique elements, but I would imagine you don't have to go through the process of creating an `Iterator`.

Merely making use of [`List.contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) is sufficient - if the list doesn't contain the element, add it in, otherwise, throw the exception*.

```
public void addProduct(Product theProduct) throws ProductAlreadyExistsException {
    if(allProducts.contains(theProduct)) {
        throw new ProductAlreadyExistsException("Not unique!");
    }
    allProducts.add(theProduct);
}
```

<sup>*:  Throwing the exception is a bit silly IMO.  That should only be reserved for truly exceptional behavior.  You're probably better off with a `Set` of some sort instead.</sup>

Comment: Appart from knowing that there are no duplicates, a Set will also be more efficient on lookups.

Comment: Unfortunately, the id is not getting created.. Id is null.. Should I change the constructor. I have the following code in the contructor. public Product(String name, double price, DeptCode code) {
  this(null, name, price, code);
 }

 public Product(Integer id, String name, double price, DeptCode code) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
  this.dept = code;

Comment: Wouldn't the ID be bound to the `Product` object anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Makoto's answer is a simple way to make sure that an object is unique in a `List`.

Additionally you need to make sure to implement the `equals(Object obj)` method in the class of the objects, you want to add to the list. The `List.contains()` method calls `equals(yourObject)` on each object it contains and returns `true`, as soon as `equals(yourObject)` returns true for any of the objects in the `List`.

Here you can see a good implementation of `equals(Object obj)` you could use in your `Product` class.

```
public class Product {
    //Other methods here
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(this == obj) 
            return true;
        if(obj == null)
            return false;
        if(this.getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Product product = (Product)obj;
        boolean result = true;
        //Compare fields of this with fields of product and set result
        return result;
    }
}
```